# Spread-spectrum systems and multipath fading

Tags: frequency-spectrum

I didn't find a suitable tag for this, but figured it would fit under "Frequency spectrum".

Which of the Spread-spectrum systems listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spread_spectrum) are most resistant to multipath fading? Please, briefly tell me why?

The Wikipedia article above lists these (or a combination of at least 2?):
**FHSS**: Frequency-hopping spread spectrum.
**DSSS**: Direct-sequence spread spectrum.
 
**THSS**: Time-hopping spread spectrum.
**CSS**:  Chirp spread spectrum.

Are there other distinct techniques the article doesn't list?

--gv

Comment: This is way too broad a question. Multipath fading comes in various forms, the fading parameters and the system parameters interact in various ways, and the question "Which is best against multipath?" does not necessarily have a unique answer. As in so many other things, it depends.

Answer (score 1):

FHSS is hopping between the carrier frequencies. Therefore, if a carrier is in the deep fade, it is probable that the others are not (assuming that the frequency hops independently experience the fading effect). If you are using a strong coding technique (such as Turbo, LDPC), the fast fading effect brings an enormous amount of diversity gain!